# Have two Javascripts on one page, other one stops the other from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have two different javascripts running on my page. One for a slideshow and another for a timed image swap. I can only get one or the other to work, depending on which one of the scripts is lower in the code. I read many tutorials and it seemed adding `<body onload="func1();func2()">` would fix the problem but it did not.

I have made two sample pages

Where image swap works but slide show does not show up

http://pancakeparadise.com/shirtswap.html

Where slide show shows up and works but images do not swap out

http://pancakeparadise.com/shirtswap1.html

Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function func2(){

        $('ul#portfolio').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 4000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '500px'
        });
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="func1();func2()">

<div id="wholebody">
<section id="slideshow">
<aside id="slides">
<a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt ="" >    </a>
<a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""></a>
<a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""></a>
<a href="/portfolio.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""></a>
</aside>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function func1() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 980,
    height: 500,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4500,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true
    }
  });
});
</script>
</section>
<aside id="frontbubbles">
<aside id="shirtswapfront">
<p id="fronttextheader"><a href="shirtswap.html">Shirt Swap!</a></p>
<ul id="portfolio">
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
</aside>
</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind putting this into a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Try using bootstrap for your top "carousel"... If you like I can post some code examples. It is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two jQuery files included in the same HTML page which is causing the conflict. Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('ul#portfolio').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 4000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '500px'
        });
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 980,
    height: 500,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4500,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wholebody">
<section id="slideshow">
<aside id="slides">
<a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt ="" >    </a>
<a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""></a>
<a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""></a>
<a href="/portfolio.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""></a>
</aside>

</section>
<aside id="frontbubbles">
<aside id="shirtswapfront">
<p id="fronttextheader"><a href="shirtswap.html">Shirt Swap!</a></p>
<ul id="portfolio">
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
</aside>
</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch with the jquery files, I missed that at first.

Comment: Did you try running my code? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @BasitNizami Sorry I have been testing it out. I could not get the slide show to show up still though. I made a page that shows what you told me to do. http://pancakeparadise.com/shirtswap3.html. A person with an answer below you made a fiddle that has it working perfectly but I was unable to recreate it. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @BasitNizami This is the link to the fiddle of it working currectly http://jsfiddle.net/z5yeLq2k/

Comment: You're using a very very old jQuery version. 1.2.3. Try switching to a newer version and it should solve your problem. Edit: I have edited my answer to switch the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up your code a little bit... dont use body onload both functions and then define one of the functions later in the code... well here it goes, this worked for me...

```js
$(document).ready(function func2(){
   $('ul#portfolio').innerfade({
    speed: 'slow',
    timeout: 4000,
    type: 'sequence',
    containerheight: '500px'
   });
  });


$(document).ready(function func1() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 980,
        height: 500,
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 4500,
          swap: true,
    pauseOnHover: true
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<div id="wholebody">
<section id="slideshow">
<aside id="slides">
    <a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt ="" /></a>
    <a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="/services.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="/portfolio.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" id="frontpicturesize" alt=""/></a>
  </aside>
</section>
<aside id="frontbubbles">
<aside id="shirtswapfront">
<p id="fronttextheader"><a href="shirtswap.html">Shirt Swap!</a></p>
<ul id="portfolio">
 <li>
  <a href="">
   <img src="http://pancakeparadise.com/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="">
   <img src="http://pancakeparadise.com/img/2.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="">
   <img src="http://pancakeparadise.com/img/3.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="">
   <img src="http://pancakeparadise.com/img/4.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="">
   <img src="http://pancakeparadise.com/img/5.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
 </li>
     <li>
  <a href="">
   <img src="http://pancakeparadise.com/img/6.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
</aside>
</aside>
</div>
```

now add your css and js files in the head like usual... it should work. here is a fiddle link for it as well  http://jsfiddle.net/z5yeLq2k/

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this! I see it is working perfectly in the the fiddle, I tried putting it on my page though and the slideshow still doesn't show up. I must not have it correct. I made this page http://pancakeparadise.com/shirtswap2.html. If you could please tell me what I did wrong there I would extremely appreciate it!

Comment: Got it solved, Was using an older jquery. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you want both of these functions to execute, the easiest way possible is to not put them in separate functions, or to not put them in functions at all. Here is what I mean...

```
$(document).ready(
    $('ul#portfolio').innerfade({
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 4000,
        type: 'sequence',
        containerheight: '500px'
    });
    $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 980,
        height: 500,
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 4500,
          swap: true,
          pauseOnHover: true
        }
     });
);
```

Outside of functions, as soon as the document.ready executes (once the page is done loading), both of those pieces of code will be executed sequentially.

EDIT: Also, as was said in another answer, you are including jquery twice...don't do that.